# Confusion surrounding the use of "?", as no value is assumed

Tags: c++, arguments

```
 std::string qfunc(unsigned int n, unsigned int base) 
 {
     std::string s; 
     do
     {
         unsigned int digit = n % base;
         s += digit < 10 ? '0' + digit :'a' + digit - 10;
         n /= base;
     } while (n != 0);
     ...
```

I have recently become acquainted with the 
"`condition ? if_true : if_false`" argument, however, I am confused by the `if_true` and `if_false` statements. What variable are we exactly setting to `'0' + digit` or `'a' + digit - 10` pending the validity of the condition?

at the moment wouldn't `'0' + digit` or `'a' + digit - 10` simply be statements that have no bearing on any variable in the code?

If someone could give me clarity on this topic, I would be very grateful.

Comment: `s += (result of ternary)`

Comment: It’s being "added" to `s`, I’m not sure what the confusion is. It’s an expression.

Comment: `'0' + digit` value would be one of `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'6'`, `'7'`, `'8'`, `'9'`.

Comment: Ternary returns value: `condition ? true_value : false_value`

Comment: I prefer more portable `s += "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopkrstuvwxyz"[digit];` (assuming `digit < 36`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What variable are we exactly setting to '0' + digit or 'a' + digit -10 pending the validity of the condition?

Simplify the line

```
s += digit < 10 ? '0' + digit :'a' + digit - 10;
```

to

```
char temp = (digit < 10) ? ('0' + digit) : ('a' + digit - 10);
s += temp;
```

That line adds a character corresponding to the digit to `s`. If the numerical value of the digit is less than 10, the corresponding character will be `0`-`9`. If the numerical value of the digit is greater than or equal to 10 (presumably it is less then 16), the corresponding character will be `a`-`f`. However, the code will gladly work with the values of digit greater than or equal to 16. In that case, characters `g` and up will be added to `s`.

Comment: `'a'`-`'z'` is not guarantied to be contiguous BTW.

Comment: @Jarod42, Thanks for pointing that out. It's an easy one to miss when ASCII encoding is so dominant.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator tests an expression (in your case digit < 10), and returns if_true if it's true, if_false if it's false.

From your example, this:

```
 s += digit < 10 ? '0' + digit :'a' + digit - 10
```

could also be written as:

```
if (digit < 10) {
    s += '0' + digit;
} else {
    s += 'a' + digit - 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to replace the conditional operator with simple `if` statements:

```
digit = n%b;
if (digit < 10){
    s += '0' + digit;
} else {
    s += 'a' + digit - 10;
}
```

In the first case, if `digit` is between 0 and 9 inclusive, the string `s` has the corresponding character from`'0'` through `'9'` appending. In the second case, if the `digit` is greater than or equal to 10, the corresponding alphabetic character is used. Overall, this performs the following mapping, assuming base is less than or equal to 36:

- 0 : `'0'`
- 1 : `'1'`
- ...
- 9 : `'9'`
- 10 : `'a'`
- 11 : `'b'`
- ...
- 35 : `'z'`

Comment: Whereas `'0'`-`'9'` is guarantied to be contiguous, it is not the case of `'a'`-`'z'`.

Comment: @Jarod42 would it then be more correct to write `s += "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[i]` ?

Comment: Yes (with same restriction digit).